# Is there a Perl Tk Text widget that supports line folding?

Tags: perl

I am trying to build a Perl TK text widget that supports line folding (similar to Visual Studio folding capabilities).

1. Is there an existing one already? (tried googling it, and searching CPAN, didn't find any)
2. Is there a way to make few lines disappear in the `Tk::Text` widget? (so i can write the logic behind the folding routines...)

Comment: The Vim Editor doesn't match your needs?

Comment: @JohnDoe: the Vim Editor is my reference... :), but Perl Tk is our language due to other reasons i can't describe here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eliding Text

You can actually include text in the widget that is not displayed; this is known as "elided" text, and is made available using the "elide" configuration option for tags. You can use this to implement for example an outliner, a "folding" code editor, or even just to bury some extra meta-data intermixed with your text. When specifying positioning with elided text you have to be a bit more careful, and so commands that deal with positions have extra options to either include or ignore the elided text.

[Giving Thanks to the references](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html)